# How to configure JBoss/Quartz to run Spring job?

Tags: spring, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to JBoss, having been using tomcat for years.  I have a Spring 3.0.x application in which I need to run a job on a regular basis.  In the past, I would simply create my job class as a regular POJO, and then create my job/trigger as Spring's CronTriggerBean passing a MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean as my jobDetail.

Ex:

```
  <bean id="session.manage.UserSessionPurgeAction.trigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
            <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */5 * * * ? *" />
            <property name="jobDetail">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
                      <property name="name"><idref bean="session.manage.UserSessionPurgeAction" /></property>
                      <property name="group" value="cleanup" />
                            <property name="targetObject" ref="session.manage.UserSessionPurgeAction" />
                            <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
                            <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
                    </bean>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

On this new project, the system architect has called for running the Spring application under JBoss 6.  I know that JBoss has a quartz scheduler built in, so I am not sure how to package/declare my job such that it is using JBoss' scheduler as opposed to building it into the app as I have done in the past.

I've searched online, but cannot seem to find the necessary glue information that I need.  I know that there is a @Schedule annotation in javax.ejb but is that all I need to add to my method?  I would think/expect that I need additional configuration somewhere, but not sure where.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: You don't need to - just keep using quartz bundled into your app like you do already, it'll work fine.

Comment: Do you run into any problems when you try to run your app as-is?

Comment: @skaffman: how do you know? :)

Comment: @abalogh: Because I've done it before.

Comment: Haven't tried it under jBoss with my current code and embedded quartz.  But my architect wants/insists on using the bundled jBoss one.  Not sure why.  But that was a decision imposed upon me.  Hence the need/desire to find a way to reference it.  I would not expect problems if I was using my own scheduler, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the jboss one, I would try matching the schedulerName property passed to SchedulerFactoryBean with one of the bundled scheduler. The bundled scheduler can be retrieved via JNDI, it's under jndi name "Quartz" I think.

Have a look at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#createScheduler, it tries to look up the scheduler in static SchedulerRepository first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Am looking into this, but the immediate question that comes up is if I will be able to configure schedules at the container level, or if I still need to configure the triggers in my app and simply have on/off control of all triggers in the container.  Do you know if there is any ability to modify/set triggers in JBoss calling spring beans?

Comment: I haven't used the built in scheduler. You sure can access it via JNDI or possibly quartz SchedulerRepository. Thus you should be able to add your triggers in the spring way. I don't know though what it would look like to manipulate them from jboss console or other container tools.